# Why is this triple product zero?

Tags: vectors

The triple product is given as:-
$$ \vec A \cdot(\vec B \times \vec A) $$
$$ \vec A \cdot((-AB\sin\theta))$$
$$ -A\cdot AB\sin\theta \cdot \cos\theta$$
But the book says the answer is zero, I tried searching this on wikipedia but with no success, so how is it possible? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Keep in mind that $AB\sin\theta$ is not $A\times B$, but the magnitude of $A\times B$ (with a sign indicating direction).

Comment: @user2468338: What is $\theta$ in $\sin\theta$?  What is $\theta$ in $\cos \theta$?  Are they the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't take the dot product that you did because $-AB\sin\theta$ is a magnitude, not a vector. By the triple product rule, we have

$$A\cdot(B\times A)=B\cdot(A\times A)$$

however, $A\times A=0$, so we get $0$.

And if you want a more intuitive reason, $A\times B$ creates a vector orthogonal to both $A$ and $B$. So when you then do a dot product with $A$, you get zero because the two vectors are orthogonal, or $\cos\theta=0$.